# How the detect the current language settings using Python?

Tags: python

I want to add a support for different languages to my blender addon. So It needs to detect the user interface language which is currently using in order to decide which language I should display in my addon. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a part of the [documentation about that](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.translations.html).

The current language is indicated by: `bpy.app.translations.locale`